# Ruby gem dependency issue

Tags: ruby

Can anyone help me solve this Ruby gem dependency issue??

I'm trying to install this library described here
http://datagraph.rubyforge.org/sinatra-linkeddata/#Dependencies

Bundler gives me the following error. (Does it seem like there is an incompatibility between the 'linkeddata' gem and the 'sinatra-linkeddata' gem I'm trying to install.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "linkeddata":
  In Gemfile:
    sinatra-linkeddata (>= 0) ruby depends on
      linkeddata (~> 0.2.0) ruby

    linkeddata (1.1.1)
```

My gem file looks like this: how should I modify it.

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem "nokogiri"
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'rdf'
gem 'sparql'
gem 'linkeddata'
gem 'sass'
gem 'tilt', '>= 1.3.4', '~> 1.3'
gem 'thin'
gem 'sinatra-linkeddata'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `bundle update`. If that doesn't work you can modify `gem 'linkeddata'` to `gem 'linkeddata', '~> 0.2.0'` in order to match the dependency of `sinatra-linkeddata` and then run `bundle update linkeddata`

Comment: Running `bundle update` without specifying a gem updates _all_ gems, which is almost never what you want.